# Fluent-bit. Why there are no Kubernetes fields in Kibana, fields for example, namespace, pod name, etc?

Tags: kubernetes, fluent

My Fluent-bit 1.8.9.

**I use two containers inside a pod:**

Container1: App

Container2: Fluent-bit

I mounted a common volume to both containers. Fluent-bit correctly reads the logs that container1 writes to the shared volume and transfers them to the Elastic.
But I can't understand why there are no Kubernetes fields in Kibana, fields for example, namespace, pod name, etc?

**Here is my fluent-bit config:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.stand }}-fluent-bit-config
  labels:
    k8s-app: fluent-bit
data:
  # Configuration files: server, input, filters and output
  # ======================================================
  fluent-bit.conf: |
    [SERVICE]
        Flush         1
        Log_Level     info
        Daemon        off
        Parsers_File  parsers.conf
        HTTP_Server   On
        HTTP_Listen   0.0.0.0
        HTTP_Port     2020

    @INCLUDE input-kubernetes.conf
    @INCLUDE filter-kubernetes.conf
    @INCLUDE output-elasticsearch.conf

  input-kubernetes.conf: |
    [INPUT]
        Name              tail
        Tag               jsonk8s.*
        Path              /var/log/containers/*.json, /var/log/containers2/*.json
        Read_from_head    true
        Parser  json

  filter-kubernetes.conf: |
    [FILTER]
        Name                kubernetes
        Match               jsonk8s.*
        Kube_URL            https://kubernetes.default.svc:443
        Kube_CA_File        /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
        Kube_Token_File     /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
        Kube_Tag_Prefix     jsonk8s.var.log.containers.
        Merge_Log           Off
        K8S-Logging.Parser  On
        K8S-Logging.Exclude Off
        Buffer_Size         0 

  output-elasticsearch.conf: |
    [OUTPUT]
        Name            es
        Match           jsonk8s.*
        Host            ${FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST}
        Port            ${FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT}
        Index jsonk8s-code_index
        Type jsonk8s-code_type

  parsers.conf: |
    [PARSER]
        Name   json
        Format json
        Time_Key time
        Time_Format %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z
```

**And this is a screenshot in Kibana:**
[image]

**Logs Fluent-bit:**

```
Fluent Bit v1.8.9                                                                                                                                                                                                                         │
│ * Copyright (C) 2019-2021 The Fluent Bit Authors                                                                                                                                                                                          │
│ * Copyright (C) 2015-2018 Treasure Data                                                                                                                                                                                                   │
│ * Fluent Bit is a CNCF sub-project under the umbrella of Fluentd                                                                                                                                                                          │
│ * https://fluentbit.io                                                                                                                                                                                                                    │
│ [2022/01/13 10:00:58] [ info] [engine] started (pid=1)                                                                                                                                                                                    │
│ [2022/01/13 10:00:58] [ info] [storage] version=1.1.5, initializing...                                                                                                                                                                    │
│ [2022/01/13 10:00:58] [ info] [storage] in-memory                                                                                                                                                                                         │
│ [2022/01/13 10:00:58] [ info] [storage] normal synchronization mode, checksum disabled, max_chunks_up=128                                                                                                                                 │
│ [2022/01/13 10:00:58] [ info] [cmetrics] version=0.2.2                                                                                                                                                                                    │
│ [2022/01/13 10:00:58] [ info] [filter:kubernetes:kubernetes.0] https=1 host=kubernetes.default.svc port=443                                                                                                                               │
│ [2022/01/13 10:00:58] [ info] [filter:kubernetes:kubernetes.0] local POD info OK                                                                                                                                                          │
│ [2022/01/13 10:00:58] [ info] [filter:kubernetes:kubernetes.0] testing connectivity with API server...                                                                                                                                    │
│ [2022/01/13 10:00:58] [ warn] [filter:kubernetes:kubernetes.0] could not get meta for POD test-json-rr-fbhd-delivery-xml-worker-app-deployment-76d95w76qb                                                                                 │
│ [2022/01/13 10:00:58] [ info] [http_server] listen iface=0.0.0.0 tcp_port=2020                                                                                                                                                            │
│ [2022/01/13 10:00:58] [ info] [sp] stream processor started                                                                                                                                                                               │
│ [2022/01/13 10:01:58] [ warn] [filter:kubernetes:kubernetes.0] invalid pattern for given tag jsonk8s.var.log.containers2.rrbpm-app-log.json                                                                                               │
│ [2022/01/13 10:01:58] [ info] [input:tail:tail.0] inotify_fs_add(): inode=1966188 watch_fd=1 name=/var/log/containers2/rrbpm-app-log.json                                                                                                 │
│ [2022/01/13 10:01:59] [ warn] [filter:kubernetes:kubernetes.0] invalid pattern for given tag jsonk8s.var.log.containers2.rrbpm-app-log.json                                                                                               │
│ [2022/01/13 10:01:59] [ warn] [filter:kubernetes:kubernetes.0] invalid pattern for given tag jsonk8s.var.log.containers2.rrbpm-app-log.json                                                                                               │
│ [2022/01/13 10:02:02] [ warn] [filter:kubernetes:kubernetes.0] invalid pattern for given tag jsonk8s.var.log.containers2.rrbpm-app-log.json                                                                                               │
│ [2022/01/13 10:02:02] [ warn] [filter:kubernetes:kubernetes.0] invalid pattern for given tag jsonk8s.var.log.containers2.rrbpm-app-log.json
```

Comment: Did you see [this similar problem](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit-kubernetes-logging/issues/46)? Did this page help you?